# Amazon access key showing in URL for Carrierwave and Fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I just switched from storing my images uploaded via Carrierwave locally to using Amazon s3 via the fog gem in my Rails 3.1 app. While images are being added, when I click on an image in my application, the URL is providing my access key and a signature. Here is a sample URL (XXX replaced the string with the info):

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/uploads/photo/image/2/IMG_4842.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Signature=XXX%3D&Expires=1332093418
```

This is happening in development (localhost:3000) and when I am using heroku for production. Here is my uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 include CarrierWave::RMagick
 storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  process :convert => :jpg
  process :resize_to_limit => [640, 640] 
  version :thumb do
    process :convert => :jpg
    process :resize_to_fill => [280, 205]
  end
  version :avatar do
    process :convert => :jpg
    process :resize_to_fill => [120, 120]
  end
end
```

And my config/initializers/fog.rb :

```
 CarrierWave.configure do |config| 
  config.fog_credentials = { 
     :provider               => 'AWS', 
     :aws_access_key_id      => 'XXX', 
     :aws_secret_access_key  => 'XXX',
   } 
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucketname' 
  config.fog_public     = false
end
```

Anyone know how to make sure this information isn't available?

UPDATE: Adding view and controller code:
from a partial in users/show.html.erb:

```
<% if @user.photos.any? %>
  <% for photo in @user.photos %>
    <li class="span4 hidey">
    <div class="thumb_box">
      <%=link_to(image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb).to_s), photo.image_url.to_s,   
                                                       :class=>"lb_test") %>
      ...
    </div>    
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

users_controller.rb:

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
```

UPDATE: Adding an error page I get when removing the access key information from the url:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>47077D6EC13AD1D8</RequestId>
     <HostId>+HTeODcWTqv3gbRIAwf+lI6sPzfNTegDXjT9SnMdqrYr7gLD1TD0qN+OgMLwA1JO
     </HostId>
 </Error>
```

Comment: Kevin, I'm guessing the issue is in your view or controller. Unless you need another convert version. Can you post the code?

Comment: Hi Ed, I added the code from one of the views and the controller action where this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you evaluate photo.image.url.to_s in the console? Does it point to a real image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is a signed-url. Without the full url (including key,signature,expires), you'll get an access denied. It is working exactly as it should. And I am guessing the key is just a public key, that is useless without your private key (which AWS has).

Comment: ah I see. You are correct that the access key is what I set as my "aws_access_key" in the uploader. It just seemed odd that it would be included in the URL. So none of this information would give someone access to my bucket?

Comment: Nope. And the signature is hashed with both the expires and your public key, which could not be generated (or checked, as AWS will do) without your secret key. It's pretty neat.

Answer (score 6):

Remove

```
config.fog_public     = false
```

That's a non-default value :)

Answer (score -1):

Try photo.image.url instead of photo.image_url. That's what I'm using.

Comment: photo.image.url and photo.image_url are both the same url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/uploads/photo/image/2/IMG_4842.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Signature=XXX%3D&Expires=1332093418. If i try to remove the access key information, and just use https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/uploads/photo/image/2/IMG_4842.jpg i get the error page I am adding to my original post above

Comment: could it be an amazon s3 setting? It looks like it is requiring the access key information in the URL when issuing a GET request and just not hiding it from the user.. or something like that